# Can the cardinality of a specific set containing a variable be proven?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was studying continued fractions of square roots and found that for the set$M=\{(x-1)^2+1,...,x^2-1\}$the cardinality appears to be $2(x-1)$. Now from what I understand, you can't really prove the cardinality without sitting down and counting out all the elements of the set. However, that's not an option with this set, as you will have to go from $(x-1)^2+1$ to $(x-1)^2+n$ before you reach the element $x^2-1$.

So am I wondering after a wild goose here or is there another way to look at this that would explain why $2(x-1)$ seems to work every time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $(x-1)^2 + 2(x-1) = x^2 - 1$, and so by the time you have counted $2(x-1)$-many elements of the set, you have reached $x^2-1$.

Formally, the cardinality of a finite set $X$ is the unique $n \in \mathbb{N}$ for which there exists a bijection $[n] \to X$, where $[n] = \{ 1, 2, \dots, n \}$. In this case, the bijection $[2(x-1)] \to X$ is given by $k \mapsto (x-1)^2 + k$. The bijection itself depends on the value of $x$, but that's fine.